# Shopify add prefix to product pages title in head section

Tags: html, shopify, shopify-template

I'm looking to add a prefix text to product pages on the Shopify theme "Enterprise 2.0". I done this previously on a different theme by adding this code block to theme.liquid. However the Enterprise theme seems to work a bit differently.

```
        {% if template == 'product' %}
  <title>Buy {{ seo_page_title }}</title>
{% else %}
  <title>{{ seo_page_title }}</title>
{% endif %}
```

I can't seem to find anywhere anywhere what is setting the page title tag in any of the .liquid files and the pages seem to be made up of sections.

Any pointers?

[Link to example product page](https://gerconstruction.co.uk/collections/external/products/mapei-mapesil-ac-silicone-310ml-all-colours)

```
        {% if template == 'product' %}
  <title>Buy {{ seo_page_title }}</title>
{% else %}
  <title>{{ seo_page_title }}</title>
{% endif %}
```

Was expecting "Buy " to prefix the product name in the title tag on product pages.